# Using NTFS-3G to write to an external hard drive results in error code 100102

Tags: macos, terminal, hard-drive, external-disk, ntfs

I have an external Seagate hard drive that is recognised and works on Windows computers but not on my MacBook Air which I am currently using. I am able to mount the hard drive in read-only mode but I want to write files to it from my computer. Using the Paragon Driver software offered by Seagate does not work for me, as I am only able to mount my hard drive in read-only mode.

I have installed NTFS-3G using Homebrew, following the instructions on this [tutorial site](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/solving-the-read-only-external-hard-drive-problem-on-your-mac/). After installing NTFS-3G, I was able to copy a folder to my hard drive. However, the size of the folder is 4 GB, so it took some time to be copied. However, when the folder copy progress bar reached the end, I received the following error message:

[image]

And the folder was not copied. I have tried copying it another time to my hard drive to see if it would work but have still received the same error. I am not sure why this error message is occurring and how I can resolve it. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: If you have a Seagate drive, then remove NTFS-3G and please install the better [Paragon Driver for macOS](https://www.seagate.com/in/en/support/software/paragon/) to properly enable read and write support for NTFS on Seagate drives. (NTFS-3G is a bit buggy). Note that this will only work with Seagate drives. On other manufacturers drives, NTFS will only be read-only.

Comment: Didn't you find any workaround your situation ? I do have the exact same problem on my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe commercial products like iBoysoft NTFS for Mac, Paragon NTFS for Mac, and Tuxera NTFS for Mac is more compatible with recent tech.

Comment: Is this the accepted answer because the OP was only able to fix his issue by installing one of these tools ? @ceno980

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error message and you can't find anything about the error code on the internet. I tried copying with terminal where I encountered several ACL errors and the files won't show up in Finder, for which I found the solution here: [Error: could not copy extended attributes (but it is working) #363](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/issues/363)

You need to mount the drive with `auto_xattr`, then copying with finder works completely.

e.g.

```
sudo mount /opt/homebrew/bin/ntfs-3g -o auto_xattr /dev/disk? /Volumes/NTFS
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - I actually got the 100102 error right when starting to copy the first file. I could get around it by copying files manually from within the Terminal. However, the copy was very slow - like 20MB/min or so.